# Generate a random number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a question that requires me to use `random()` to generate a number between 0 to 9999 with equal probability. I know I can scale `random()` by multiplying it, but I'm getting mainly 4 digit numbers. Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: out of 0-9999 numbers, 1000-9999 are 4 digit numbers. So, it is highly probable that you get a 4 digit number when each number is equally probable.

Comment: *I know I can scale random() by multiplying it*: You should not do that ;)

Comment: Btw: welcome to Stackoverflow. The reason you got a downvote is, because there are plenty of questions about generating a random number between x and y, so you should search for your question first, before blindly asking. Please take yourself some time to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I actually tried to search for a similar question but I couldn't.

Answer (score 6):

Use `randint`.

```
>>> import random as r
>>> r.randint(0,9999)
6935
>>> r.randint(0,9999)
5550
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion, assuming you want a random integer:

```
from random import randint
print(randint(0,9999))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 4-digit numbers because they are 90% of your range, so it's expected. However, you don't need to scale `random()`, instead use `random.randint`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

# retruns n numbers with uniform(equal) propability between a and b
# thus for each x in arr: a <= x < b
arr = np.random.uniform(a, b, n)
```

If you want them to be integers

```
arr = np.round(arr).astype(int)
```

see also here: [np.random.uniform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html)

Comment: There is no need to use an external library like numpy, to generate a random number, but yes, this should work